# Spring data Dynamic projection without creating projection dto/interface

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data, projection

I use Spring data by extending SimpleJpaRepository, Sometimes we need only a few special fields of an entity on sometimes other fields. if we create a projection class or interface for every need, there will be many classes that are used only for one application. is there any way to pass fields/columns as map/list to createQuery ?

Answer (score 0):

> I use Spring data by extending `SimpleJpaRepository`

That is at least weird, if not wrong. you'd normally extend on or multiple of Spring Data interfaces.

Anyway, yes this is possible like so:

> Is there a way to achieve this?

Yes, there is.

Version 2.6 RC1 of Spring Data JPA introduced fluent APIs for Query By Example,  Specifications, and Querydsl.
This you can use among other things to configure projections. Note  that only interface projections are supported.

You can use projections like this:

```java
interface SomeRepository extends CrudRepository, JpaSpecificationExecutor{}
```

```java
MyService {

    @Autowired
    SomeRepository repository;

    void doSomething(){

        List<User> users = repository.findBy(
            someSpecification, 
            q -> q.project("firstname", "roles").all()
        );
        // ...
    }
}
```

It will return an entity, but only the fields given in the `project` clause will be filled.